# A little Pizza menu using MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to write a little menu in MATLAB for a user who wants to order pizza using the ‘input’ function to ask for a few options. For example, I can start by asking whether the pizza should be vegetarian if 1 = yes, then I ask for different types of veggies, if 2 = no ask for different meat options etc.

So far I tried as follows using 'if/else if/else' loop: I created 4 menus: vegetrian(2 menus) and Nonvegetrian(2 menus), as follows, But, in some steps it doesn't work. Can someone help me pls?

```
a=input('Vegetrian: ');
a1=input('Mix Vegetable:');
a2=input('SAAG:')

b=input('Nonvegetrian: ');
b1=input('chicken PIZZA:');
b2=input('Cheese PIZZA:')

if a==1 
    disp(a1);
elseif a1==2
    disp(b);
elseif b==1
    disp(b1);
elseif b1==2
    dip(b2);
else 
    disp('Not Available');
end
```

Comment: It's not clear at all what you're trying to do. Can you show some expected input/output?

Comment: I couldn't go further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The required logic for the selection is a little more complex.

- you can first ask which type of Pizza: Vegetarian or Non Vegetarian
- then, for each option, you have to propose the two alternatives
- also the error conditions have to be considered:

  - wrong selection of the type (Vegetarian or Non Vegetarian)
  - wrong selection of the Vegetarian or Non Vegetarian alternatives.

A possible implementation could be:

```
%
% Define the types of Pizza
%
veg_type{1}='Mix Vegetable:';
veg_type{2}='SAAG';
non_veg{1}='Chicken Pizza';
non_veg{2}='Cheese Pizza';
%
% Ask for Vegetarian Pizza
%
a=input('Which Pizza do you want? Vegetarian = 1, Non Vegetarian = 2): ');
%
% Analyse the selection
%
% Vegetarian options
%
if(a == 1)
   sprintf('Available Vegetarian Pizza: \n\t%s=1\n\t%s=2' ,veg_type{1},veg_type{2})
   a1=input('Select your Vegetarian Pizza: ');
   if(a1 == 1)
      disp('You have select a Mix Vegetable Pizza')
   elseif(a1 == 2)
      disp('You have select a SAAG Pizza')
   else
      disp('Invalid Selection: Pizza not available')
   end
elseif(a == 2)
   %
   % Non Vegetarian options
   %
   sprintf('Available Non Vegetarian Pizza: \n\t%s=1\n\t%s=2' ,non_veg{1},non_veg{2})
   b1=input('Select your Non Vegetarian Pizza: ');
   if(b1 == 1)
      disp('You have select a Chicken Pizza')
   elseif(b1 == 2)
      disp('You have select a Cheese Pizza')
   else
      disp('Invalid Selection: Pizza not available')
   end
   %
   % Neither Vegetarian nor Non Vegetarian
   %
else
   disp('So you do not want neither a Vegetarian nor a Non Vegetarian Pizza')
end
```

Hope this helps.

Qapla'